# How to keep div at the bottom of the window if page not full, otherwise at the end of content

Tags: footer, css

I have a div in a page (footer) and I want the following to happen with CSS:

If the page has not enough content to fill the window, the div should be at the very bottom.
If the page has enough content (and a scroll bar perhaps appears) then I want the div to be after all the content.

If I do it with position absolute etc, I can't get the second case to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for 100% min-height layout. Check out this post: [100% Min Height CSS layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238/100-min-height-css-layout).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a sticky footer.

For example: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

or if you google Sticky footer you find a few alternatives