# CSS display: table min-height not working

Tags: css

Does anyone know I can make min-height work with the latest browsers? I am using CSS tables and it seems to ignore min-height.

```
<div style="background-color: red; display: table; min-height: 100px;">
abc
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxTbQ/)

Comment: similar post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238/100-min-height-css-layout

Comment: Can you define *CSS tables*? Got some markup?

Comment: post your html, the according css and, if possible, give a link to your site (or try building a http://jsfiddle.net/) to show up your problem.

Comment: This is still a trouble with FireFox, although the bug is reported since fourteen years. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307866

Answer (score 213, accepted):

When using tables, height essentially is min-height, as tables always stretch. Just get rid of the "min-" and it will work as you expect.

Comment: This is completely unintuitive, but spot-on.  Best results seem to come with putting the "fixed" height on the innermost `display: table-cell` elements.

Comment: I haven't tested in IE but it seems Firefox is the only one still affected by this.

Comment: Confirmed that `height` works and `min-height` doesn't in Chrome 37, Safari 7 and FF 32 on mac. IE11 on Win 8.1 gives the correct behavior in both. http://jsfiddle.net/nuwcyvwn/1/

Comment: Not true. If I want a table to be AT LEAST 8in tall (I use css for print control) and it lacks enough rows to fill it, but I have a tfoot defined, I can provide a spacer row (allowed to stretch vertically), while defining height on my other rows to ensure they do not and what I get is a big gap that keeps my footer where it should be. Works great in Chrome, but not FF or the PDf converter I'm using; wkhtmltopdf. Yes, height works, but doesn't mean the same thing semantically as min-height.

Answer (score 8):

Use `height: 1px;` on the table or any value. Basically you need to give table some height to make it work with `min-height`. Having only `min-height` won't work on tables on firefox.

Comment: OP is asking how to make it work with latest browser's. I just gave him a solution. How is it not accurate?

Comment: give some height like height:1px as you said, then it started working

Answer (score 5):

Solution for Firefox

Add **height** to unlock setting the **min-height**

```
div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

The number in height can be any other real value less or equal to min-height for making it work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using `display:table;` or any deeper property like `display:table-cell;` consider using `height` instead of `min-height`. As in tables height = min-height considering the auto-span feature in them.