# Using qTranslate-X on Slider

Tags: html, wordpress, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

Our Wordpress web site using a free version of Responsive Brix. We have 2 different languages on with qTranslate-X.

We use it like [:en]Widget[:tr]Bilesen on other parts of web site.

But this doesnt work on slider. I've seen some ppl changed some codes in their sliders to make it work.

Like this one: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-the-slider-multi-language

Can i do that too?

Here is my sliders code:

```
<?php
global $hoot_theme, $hoot_style_builder;

if ( !isset( $hoot_theme->slider ) || empty( $hoot_theme->slider ) )
    return;

// Ok, so we have a slider to show. Now, lets display the slider.

/* Let developers alter slider via global $hoot_theme */
do_action( 'hoot_slider_start', 'html' );

/* Create Data attributes for javascript settings for this slider */
$atts = $class = $gridstyle = '';
if ( isset( $hoot_theme->sliderSettings ) && is_array( $hoot_theme->sliderSettings ) ) {

    if ( !empty( $hoot_theme->sliderSettings['class'] ) )
        $class .= ' ' . sanitize_html_class( $hoot_theme->sliderSettings['class'] );

    if ( !empty( $hoot_theme->sliderSettings['id'] ) )
        $atts .= ' id="' . sanitize_html_class( $hoot_theme->sliderSettings['id'] ) . '"';
    foreach ( $hoot_theme->sliderSettings as $setting => $value )
        $atts .= ' data-' . $setting . '="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"';

    if ( !empty( $hoot_theme->sliderSettings['min_height'] ) ) {
        // use height instead of min-height (firefox) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790222/
        $gridstylearray = $hoot_style_builder->css_rule_sanitized_array( 'height', $hoot_theme->sliderSettings['min_height'] . 'px' );
        if( is_array( $gridstylearray ) ) {
            foreach ( $gridstylearray as $property => $value ) {
                $gridstyle .= " $property: " . $value['value'] . ';';
            }
        }
    }

}

/* Start Slider Template */
$slide_count = 1; ?>
<ul class="lightSlider<?php echo $class; ?>"<?php echo $atts; ?>><?php
    foreach ( $hoot_theme->slider as $slide ) :
        if ( !empty( $slide['image'] ) || !empty( $slide['content'] ) ) :

            $slidestyle = '';
            $slidestylearray = $hoot_style_builder->backgroundarray( $slide['background'] );
            if( is_array( $slidestylearray ) ) {
                foreach ( $slidestylearray as $property => $value ) {
                    $slidestyle .= " $property: " . $value['value'] . ';';
                }
            }

            $is_custom_bg = ( isset( $slide['background']['type'] ) && 'custom' == $slide['background']['type'] ) ? ' is-custom-bg ' : '';

            $column = ( !empty( $slide['image'] ) && !empty( $slide['content'] ) ) ? ' column-1-2 ' : ' column-1-1 ';
            $column .= ( !empty( $slide['image'] ) ) ? ' with-featured-image ' : ' no-featured-image ';

            $slide['button'] = empty( $slide['button'] ) ? __('Know More', 'responsive-brix') : $slide['button'];

            // Start Slide
            ?><li class="lightSlide hootslider-html-slide hootslider-html-slide-<?php echo $slide_count; $slide_count++; ?> <?php echo $is_custom_bg; ?>" <?php if ( !empty( $slidestyle ) ) echo ' style="' . esc_attr( $slidestyle ) . '"'; ?>>

                <div class="grid"<?php if ( !empty( $gridstyle ) ) echo ' style="' . esc_attr( $gridstyle ) . '"'; ?>>

                    <?php if ( !empty( $slide['content'] ) || !empty( $slide['url'] ) ) { ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo $column; ?> hootslider-html-slide-column hootslider-html-slide-left">
                            <?php if ( !empty( $slide['content'] ) ) { ?>
                                <div class="hootslider-html-slide-content linkstyle">
                                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $slide['content'] ) ); ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if ( !empty( $slide['url'] ) ) { ?>
                                <div class="hootslider-html-slide-link"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $slide['url'] ); ?>" <?php hoot_attr( 'hootslider-html-slide-button', 'html-slider', 'button' ); ?>><?php echo $slide['button']; ?></a></div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( !empty( $slide['image'] ) ) { ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo $column; ?> hootslider-html-slide-column hootslider-html-slide-right">
                            <img class="hootslider-html-slide-img" src="<?php echo esc_url( $slide['image'] ); ?>">
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </li><?php

        endif;
    endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes you can do that too, just try it and ask here if it doesnt work with error.

Comment: I just don't know which code to edit on my slider's code.