# Set a fixed minimum height for angular material table

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a table like so

```html
<table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8 w-full" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Username Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.username}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Email Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.email}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" [length]="count" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

And it works perfectly fine, except for when I go to the last page, where the amount of objects is less than the objects per page, because then the table shrinks in height.

This is correct:
[image]

This is how it looks on the last page:
[image]

I want the height to be same. So for it to just fill in empty rows until it's the same height as every other page. How do I do that?

Some environment information:

- Angular 11.0.4
- @angular/material ^11.2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS display: table min-height not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790222/css-display-table-min-height-not-working)

Comment: @kvetis this doesn't fix it, the last page is still crunched down and it doesn't fill out the entire space it has

Comment: adjust the css for mat-table  .mat-table {
  height: specify the height;
}

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzwjgr?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.css

Answer (score 0):

You could simply override the CSS for mat-table add the following in the component CSS or in your style.css:

```
.mat-table {
 height: /*specify the height;*/ 
}
```

if the style won't apply you could add `&#33;imporatant` and `ng:deep` as follows:

```
::ng-deep.mat-table {
 height: 500px !important;/ 
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzwjgr?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.css)

If style won't apply then you need to check the CSS class that is being applied into the table and overriding that class and adjusting the height.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.

Apply min-height to the **table** itself.

Like

```
table {
min-height: 150px;
}
or 
table ::ng-deep {
min-height: 150px;
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use `ViewEncapsulation: None` to achieve this. in `td` use `class` property

**`app.component.ts`**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app",
  styleUrls: ["app.component.css"],
  templateUrl: "app.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**`app.component.html`**

```
<table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8 w-full" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Username Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="height">{{element.username}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Email Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="height">{{element.email}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" [length]="count" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

**`app.component.css`**

```
.height {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Working **`stackblitz`** example:
**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uf1sdt?file=src/app/table-multiple-header-footer-example.css**

**Hope this helps :)**

Comment: Still doesn't work. The last page of the table is crunched down to the height of 1 row, where as I want it to be the the same height as every other page (i.e the number of rows the user selected in the paginator)

Comment: Now check the stackblitz I have updated it with paginator