# CSS: Aligning a div to the bottom of a parent div

Tags: html, css, positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/nFrp7/4/

I have a layout similar to this jsfiddle I have created. I want to know how to get the blue div to position itself at the bottom (where the red div extends) no matter what (but not using `position: fixed;` or `bottom: 0;`).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this
http://jsfiddle.net/nFrp7/10/

uses a wrap div to contain all the layout divs and uses absolute positioning for blue div

Answer (score 0):

Put a wrapper `div` around everything and apply `height:400px;` and `position:relative;` to it. Then use `position:absolute;`, `bottom:0;`, and `right:0;` on the blue `div`.

Comment: When the content within the red div expands, it does not affect the blue div's positioning.

Comment: Yeah, then you want a min-height:400px on the wrapper div and the red div.  Probably also want an overflow:hidden on the wrapper div to keep your floats pushing down the wrapper...

Answer (score 0):

<s>hmm....</s>

```
.right-main {
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
clear: both;
background-color: green;
}
```

Clear the left div?

Since EVERYTHING is a float, I don't think it's possible without some positioning.

Well there's this... [FIDDLE UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/nFrp7/9/)

But it does use positioning.

Comment: This won't work. I'm fine with using positioning, I just can't come up with how to position something in line with the bottom of the red div.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... you're referring to the CSS [100% height problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=100%25%20height).  Check this out too: [100% Min Height CSS layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238/100-min-height-css-layout).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.right-main {
      width: 100px;
      **height: 400px;**
      background-color: green;
    **position: relative;**
    } 

.bottom-right {
      background-color: blue;
      **position:absolute;**
      **bottom: 0;**
    }
```