# Why isn't my page height stopping?

Tags: css, slider, height, nivo-slider

Alright, I'm new to this website, but I heard it's the best for this kind of help so here we go. Currently I'm developing my own website, and everything is going good so far, but now that I'm adding a footer, my page wont end at the footer.
for example; http://justxp.x10.mx/test/
You see how my page continues after the footer? I've tried adding the height: 100% code, and that didn't work, I've also tried setting the height manually, and that didn't work, anybody know how I can remove the extra space? I want my footer where it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% Min Height CSS layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238/100-min-height-css-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
```

to the footer

Comment: Tried, it moved the nav in a nice position, but it still didn't remove the space below.

Comment: if you want it always on bottom, try the **position:fixed;** option :)

Comment: no I like it how it is now, all I want to do is remove the space after the footer.

Comment: i guess i just dont understand you request..
as i see it, there always be a space because of the div named "slider-wrapper theme-default", it docent have any height defined

Comment: I think that may be the problem, where would I add the height?

Comment: figured it out, had to close one of the div's.

Answer (score 0):

Give `clear:both;` to your footer.

Comment: Tried, it moved the nav in a nice position, but it still didn't remove the space below.

Comment: i think its bcs of relative position,change child element of footer also to absolute.

Comment: didn't work so I just changed back. maybe the nivo is causing it.

Comment: when i am giving clear:both,its working fine for me,can you make jsfiddle   then others can also help you