# Fill remaining height with Javascript/Jquery (100% Height Web App)

Tags: jquery, height

I'm working on a web app that I want to make it feel like an actual app, so to do that I would like to have the actual website fill 100% of the browser's height, and just have specific panes be scrollable where some are just always visible.

Below is a mockup of a potential set of panes. There will be panes in a column with variable heights determined by the contents of them, and then a scrollable pane that should fill the remaining space. Some columns may have two scrollable divs (however this is not critical to have, I could have one of those with a defined height). The fixed height divs may use percentage or pixels to determine height.

[image: Layout example]

My hope is that there is some simple Jquery I could use that in order to make the scrollable pane fill the remaining height would be to simply add a "fillheight" class or something simple like that.

I have seen some CSS solutions to this but they required a header and a footer, or they require a lot of specific styling in all the panes in the column that it makes it hard to easily create different panes on different pages. In my case I want the scrollable pane to be at any place. Potentially, on the top, middle, or bottom, also possibly nested as well.

I have looked at the script [Jquery Layout](https://layout.jquery-dev.net/) and liked it's potential, however its a bit overkill for what I need. It would be nice to resize and collapse but I dont really need that. Also the script seems like its not supported anymore, and for using this on a commercial product I'd rather not rely on an old, non-suppported script. Preferably I'd rather have a simple script, rather then a full plugin/framework.

Any help is appreciated! If I find a solution I'll update this post.

**UPDATE 1:**

I think I've figured out a solution, and using CSS only after all. It is based on a solution that was linked to be @crafter. I created a jsfiddle that shows all the use cases I described above.

http://jsfiddle.net/8BHM6/4/

Part of the key to getting this to work was using the following for the static panes:

```
.static-pane {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 15%;
    top:0;
}
```

And the following for the panes that fill the remaining height:

```
.fill {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    top:15%;
    bottom:0;
}
```

(Note theres more code involved, see the jsfiddle)

It seems to work in Chrome and IE 10 just fine, but Firefox seems to ignore the overflow:auto I have set to give scrollbars which causes the content to just be cut off. Any idea how to get this to work on Firefox?

**UPDATE 2:**

I fixed the firefox bug. I was applying a `box-sizing:brder-box` to all elements but apparently that doesn't work with firefox so I had to apply a browser specific version of `-moz-box-sizing:border-box` to them as well. This solved all the issues with Firefox.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8BHM6/6/

**UPDATE 3:**

Found a problem with Safari not showing the scrollbars of the scrollable divs, fixed it using this code that styles the scrollbars, forcing them to show. Note that it styles the scrollbars on chrome as well which is actually a nice look.

```
.fill::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
}
.fill::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.fill::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .4);
}
```

I still have an issue with IE9 though where when the scrollbars appear they are over to the left too far. Still looking into this, but Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera are all working now.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8BHM6/7/

**UPDATE 4:**

Fixed the IE9 bug. IE9 doesn't seem to like `box-sizing:border-box` when combined with overflow, so I added a IE9 hack of `box-sizing:content-box\9;` which worked.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8BHM6/8/

I posted my final solution as an answer below with a simplified version of this fiddle.

Comment: Answered : stackoverflow.com/questions/25238/100-min-height-css-layout

Comment: @crafter looks like the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5486053/2666062 from the question you linked to might be what I'm looking for. Would just need to make all of the panes absolute positioned. Need to do some testing for this though. Still open to other solutions till I can test this one thoroughly. Thanks!

Comment: I know it doesn't support IE 9 but have you considered looking at flex box? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @BlueCaret, great to hear. Post your solution.

Comment: @Pierce, unfortunately I cannot yet ignore IE9 for production yet, however flexbox would be a nice option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with, ended up fairly simple using CSS only, although a javascript solution would have been nice to make it even simpler, oh well.

To simplify this, the basics are the following code to get this to work:

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:content-box\9; /* Fix for IE9 sizing */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Fix for firefox */
}
.column {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.pane {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.fill {
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
.top {
    background:pink;
    height: 20%;
    top:0;
}
.middle {
    background:red;
    top:20%;
    bottom:50px;
}
.bottom {
    background:orange;
    height: 50px;
    bottom:0;
}

/* Fix for Safari scrollbars (also styles Chrome scrollbars) */
    .fill::-webkit-scrollbar {-webkit-appearance: none;width: 10px;}
    .fill::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .3);border-radius: 0px;}
    .fill::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {border-radius: 0px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .4);}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="pane top">Top</div>
    <div class="pane middle fill">Middle</div>
    <div class="pane bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xY3jr/3/

For a complex version of this you can look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8BHM6/8/