# My "footer" doesn't appear at the foot if the page?

Tags: css, footer

Hi i'm doing the a basic layout and i have a problem with my css. 
I have a footer tag set, but it doesnt appear at the bottom it appears a the midway point in the page.

Here is my CSS code

My "footer" doesn't appear at the foot if the page ?

I think it might be the height and width i have set but i'm not sure what to set it as prperly.

Thanks in advance

```
body
{
background: url("http://ulyssesonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/darkwood.jpg");
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}


#social {
float: right;
background-color:black;
}

#social1 {
float:right;
background-color:black;
}

#wrapper,#header,#main,#footer
{
width:100%;
}
#wrapper
{
width:960px;
height:720px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#header
{

height:100px;
background:#000;
}

#main
{

height:750px;
background:#666;
}


#footer
{
margin-bottom:-50px; 
height:50px; 
background-color:red;}
}
```

Comment: You've margin-bottom: -50px, did you notice????

Comment: i think you are facing this problem because of float

Comment: refer this to get a clear idea 
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/689290/3164682

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% Min Height CSS layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238/100-min-height-css-layout)

Answer (score 4):

Replace the footer with:

```
#footer
{  position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:50px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
background-color:red;}
```

The tutorial used: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

This is my full CSS:

```
body
{
background: url("http://ulyssesonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/darkwood.jpg");
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}


#social {
float: right;
background-color:black;
}

#social1 {
float:right;
background-color:black;
}

#wrapper,#header,#main,#footer
{
width:100%;
}
#wrapper
{
width:960px;
height:720px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#header
{

height:100px;
background:#000;
}

#main
{

height:750px;
background:#666;
}
```

And this is how i referenced it from the html:

```
<footer  id ="footer">Some footer text</footer>
```

I suspect you did not reference it correctly, with the proper id from your div?

Comment: The footer is still half way up the page.

Comment: and i had to declare the main section in a relative position

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your problem. In the footer css code you have the following:

```
#footer
{
margin-bottom:-50px; 
height:50px; 
background-color:red;}
}
```

Pretty sure the margin-bottom being a negative number is the issue. Change that to 5 or 10 and see if it appears.

Comment: It didnt make a difference. :(

Comment: That seemed like it should have worked... check this tutorial and see if that helps out. http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Comment: You have two closing brackets.

Comment: Two feet. You make me laugh. @FrantišekMaša

Answer (score 0):

i got it thanks for all your help.

i got this from summer codes answer above

```
#footer
{  position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:50px;   /* Height of the footer */
background:#6cf;
background-color:red;}
```

and i had to change the main section to

```
#main
{
position:relative;
height:100%;
background:#666;
}
```