# Dynamic CSS auto size of div

Tags: html, css

Whats wrong with this?

CSS:

```
width:auto;
height:auto;
min-width:500px;
min-height:500px;
```

The width works and dynamically re-size to the window, but the height just gets set to the min-height.

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wugu0y8f/)

Comment: can you post your full CSS?

Comment: well its not much more of the CSS, just a bg color, I'm just wondering if that suppose to work, added a JSFiddle DEMO @jmore009

Comment: possible duplicate of [100% Min Height CSS layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238/100-min-height-css-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to adjust to, you need to set

```
body,html{
   height: 100%;
}
```

and change `height` to 100% instead of auto if you want it to take up the size

```
#div1 {
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
  min-width:500px;
  min-height:500px;
  background-color:#F00;
}
```