# bootstrap 4 h-100 column won't stack properly when screen is resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with bootstrap 4 when using the h-50 and h-100 helper class and rows using columns of different breakpoints.

Take the following example :

```
<style>
    html,body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .red{
        background-color: red;
    }

    .green{
        background-color: green;
    }

    .blue{
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .purple{
        background-color: purple;
    }

</style>

xs
<section class="h-50 container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100 header_content_row purple">
        <div class="col-4 h-100 red">
            foo
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 h-100 green">
            bar
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 h-100 blue">
            whiz
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

sm
<section class="h-50 container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100 header_content_row purple">
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-100 red">
            foo
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-100 green">
            bar
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 h-100 blue">
            whiz
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

md
<section class="h-50 container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100 header_content_row purple">
        <div class="col-md-4 h-100 red">whiz
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 h-100 green">bar
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 h-100 blue">foo
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Notice that on a computer screen in full screen the rows and columns display properly with a full height BUT when resizing the screen to a smaller size the seccond section partly disappears behind the third.

Is this a bug ? 
How can this be avoided?

edit : 
[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3pa4h3kc/2)
 from isherwood shows the problem
Thanks

Comment: The code you posted doesn't repro what you describe. Is there other CSS?

Comment: I added the contents of style tag. Could it be the 100% height of body that is doing this? From my understanding it is necessary for h-100 to work properly...

Comment: Does [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3pa4h3kc/2) show the problem?

Comment: @azpublic What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @isherwood actually yes your demo shows the problem. Notice how the second section slips under the third when you resize the window to a narrow enough size that all 3 sections should have their columns stacked on top of each other.

Comment: @ZimSystem I'm trying to have bootstrap 4 behave the expected way by stacking columns on top of each other when the window is too narrow, even when using the h-100 class to have full window height columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to take the `h-100` off the inner columns.

https://www.codeply.com/go/C32tIprxQr

```
<section class="h-50 container-fluid">
  <div class="row h-100 header_content_row purple">
    <div class="col-4 red">
      foo
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 green">
      bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 blue">
      whiz
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

sm
<section class="h-50 container-fluid">
  <div class="row h-100 header_content_row purple">
    <div class="col-sm-4 red">
      foo
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 green">
      bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 blue">
      whiz
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

md
<section class="h-50 container-fluid">
  <div class="row h-100 header_content_row purple">
    <div class="col-md-4 red">whiz
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 green">bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 blue">foo
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The Bootstrap 4 row is `display:flex` so the cols will fill height. [Also, this answer explains more how percentage heights work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25249/171456).

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick interestingly. I don't understand why though ... :)